# Android отцентровать View елемент относительно другого View елемента

Tags: android, вёрстка

```
public RelativeLayout textSender(String text, String citation, String photoURI, String photoDesc, int margin, RelativeLayout prevRelative, int iterator) {
    int containerId = 100 + iterator;
    int textId = 200 + iterator;
    int citationId = 300 + iterator;
    int photoId = 400 + iterator;
    int photoDescId = 500 + iterator;
    int staples = 1000 + iterator;
    //int photoDescContainerId = 400 + iterator;

    //Конейнер всього блоку
    final RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(activity);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, (int) convertDpToPixel(margin), 0, 0);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, prevRelative.getId());
    relative.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    relative.setId(containerId);

    //Текстове поле опису новини
    final TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    textView.setLayoutParams(textParams);
    textView.setId(textId);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    if (!text.equals("")) {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }else{
        textView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    }

    //Лапки
    final ImageView staplesImage = new ImageView(activity);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams staplesImageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    staplesImageParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    staplesImageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView.getId());
    staplesImageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    staplesImage.setLayoutParams(staplesImageParams);
    staplesImage.setId(staples);
    staplesImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.staples);
    //Цитата
    final TextView citationTextView = new TextView(activity);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams citationParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    citationParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    citationParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textView.getId());
    citationParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, staplesImage.getId());
    citationTextView.setLayoutParams(citationParams);
    citationTextView.setId(citationId);
    citationTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    citationTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10);
    citationTextView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    if (!citation.equals("")) {
        citationTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }else{
        citationTextView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
        staplesImage.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
    }
    //--

    //Зображення
    final ImageView photoImage = new ImageView(activity);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams photoParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( (int)convertDpToPixel(250), (int)convertDpToPixel(250));
    photoParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    photoParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, citationTextView.getId());
    photoParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    photoImage.setLayoutParams(photoParams);
    photoImage.setId(photoId);
    photoImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    if (!photoURI.equals("")) {
        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(photoURI, photoImage);
        loader.execute();
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = loader.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        photoImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }else{
        photoImage.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
    }

    relative.addView(textView);
    relative.addView(staplesImage);
    relative.addView(citationTextView);
    relative.addView(photoImage);
    listContainer.addView(relative);
    //--
    return relative;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста! У меня есть ImageView(staplesImage) и TextView(citationTextView), мне нужно сделать так, что бы ImageView был всегда по центру относительно TextView, что бы было вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но без добавления еще одного Layout.

Comment: обязательно это делать программно?

Answer (score 1):

```
staplesImageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, citationTextView.getId()); 
staplesImageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, citationTextView.getId()); 
staplesImageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, citationTextView.getId()); 
staplesImage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам, скорее всего, нужно [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)):

```
mTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ТУТ_ССЫЛКА_НА_ЭКЗЕМПЛЯР_DRAWABLE, null, null, null);
```